# How would domestic cats react to a world with constant twilight (Kepler 186f for example)?

Tags: creature-design

I like cats and for my world I wanted domestic cats (with changes obviously) but on a different planet. But I am a complete moron to space and don't know how animals would react to constant twilight.

---

The basis for my species, called Seekers, are very catlike because millions of years ago some humans injected cat DNA into the native wildlife making the species after some trial and error of course. The species are feral and tends to be in groups from family to utterly random Seekers. They vary in color but white ones are very rare due to selection along with tortoiseshells and calicos. (The species is still development this is why I ask this.)

The planet does orbit but its parent star is very young and is a good enough distance to get some light to have life but not as much as our own planet so its in a twilight stage. The photosynthesis changed a lot. Also since there are no alien people or people really there are no buildings. Instead of taking in sunlight the plants takes the light from the animals for all animals markings glow in the dark the brighter the glow the stronger so the dimmer shows old age, sickness, young they also take in a lot more water and the other components to make up for the lack of light. The terrain is varied but the plants tends to be darker and there are more dense meadow lands than forests except one rainforest where the dark plants thrive. Also there are two moons one being a meteor caught into the orbit of the planet.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding. If you add more detail about the specifics of your world (i.e. what type of star does your planet orbit, how much distant it is from the star, what type of environment it has etc), it would help us answer your question in more detail :)

Comment: Cats are a species that evolved on Earth and are adapted to the conditions on Earth. What makes you think that cats will evolve on your twilight world?

Comment: Do you mean cat-like animals, or Earth-evolved domestic cats? As pets or feral? If pets, to humans or aliens? If not evolved there, how much time has passed since their introduction to the alien planet?

Comment: I'm just glad you mentioned Kepler 186f, because my first reaction to "how would domestic cats react to a twilight world" is that they would hiss at Bella and run away from Edward.  ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Cats are mainly active in twilight and dusk.

We, humans, have a different brain structure, we awake if we are in light and get sleepy in darkness.

Furthermore, we aren't carnivores. Carnivores tend to sleep all days, except a short wake time to quickly kill and eat somebody, maybe have sex and similar. It is about energy sparing.

We, humans, have to work all day to produce our food.

Doing a continuous twilight for cats would be similar for them as if we would live in continuous daylight. We could do it, but our daily sleep pattern became irregular.

I had seen cats in similar situation (it was an animal rescue office behind closed doors). They did as I said, they had around two active periods daily, but they did it irregularly.

Answer (score 1):

If they live on the sunward side, they'd lie around all day napping and collecting warmth from the meager sun.

On the night side they'd run back and forth playing with their toys as loudly as possible, keeping everyone awake.